# Swagger UI is not using Newtonsoft.Json to serialize decimal, instead using System.Text.json

Tags: asp.net-core, json.net, swagger-ui, jsonserializer, system.text.json

When the decimal value of "Salary" field of below POCO class is 12000M (a decimal value), the Swagger UI displays the JSON attribute values as 12000.
Whereas, **the expected JSON attribute values as 12000.0 (i.e. having a trailing zero)**.

Used the following code inside "ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)" method of startup.cs:

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Decimal;
    options.SerializerSettings.FloatFormatHandling = FloatFormatHandling.DefaultValue;
});
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Decimal;
    options.SerializerSettings.FloatFormatHandling = FloatFormatHandling.DefaultValue;
});
```

Used the following code snippet as well, but the expected output is not coming in Swagger UI.
(in Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft V6.1.4.0)

```
services.AddAwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport();
```

When the above code snippet didn't work, tried following as well.
But there is no luck.

```
services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Decimal;
        options.SerializerSettings.FloatFormatHandling = FloatFormatHandling.DefaultValue;
    });
```

Class:

```
public class Employee{
   public string EmployeeName {get; set;}
   public decimal Salary {get; set;}
   public string Department {get; set;}
}
```

**It looks like, even after adding the above code snippet, the Swagger UI is not using Newtonsoft.Json to serialize decimal, instead using System.Text.json.**

.Net Core Version is 3.1

Comment: Hello, it looks like there is a typo in your code  : should be AddSwagger and not AddAwagger...

Answer (score 6):

Install this package

```
Install-Package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft -Version 6.2.3
```

Then add this line

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport();
```