# SwaggerGen isn't recognizing my Newtonsoft JsonProperty attributes, despite AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport call

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I've just recently upgraded from Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen 4.0.1 to 6.4.0, and now the Newtonsoft Json attributes ([JsonProperty(...)] and the like) are being ignored. In particular, `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "key")]` is used all over my codebase to rename properties, and those new names are not reflected in the swagger.json.

Unlike [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68337082/swagger-ui-is-not-using-newtonsoft-json-to-serialize-decimal-instead-using-syst), I've tried `services.AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport()`, and it's not working like it should.

This is a .Net 6.0 project.

### Relevant code snippets

##### Packages installed

```
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft" Version="6.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen" Version="6.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUi" Version="6.4.0" />
```

##### Startup.cs

I'll admit I just started spamming `AddNewtonsoftJson()` once I saw there was more than one place I could/should put it. The AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson() and AddMvcCore().AddNewtonsoftJson() calls are the latest flailing I've tried, the builder.AddNewtonsoftJson() was the first attempt.

```
            var builder = services.AddMvcCore(x => {
                x.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
            });

            builder.AddNewtonsoftJson(x => {
                x.AllowInputFormatterExceptionMessages = false;

                // Default enum serialization: as a string, not a number.
                x.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
                // don't serialize nulls
                x.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;

                x.SerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore;
            });

            builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson()
                .AddJsonOptions(options => { options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter()); });

            // Homemade all-Swagger-init function, see SwaggerConfig.cs
            services.AddSwaggerPage();
```

##### SwaggerConfig.cs

You can see `services.AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport()` is called (probably correctly?) here.

```
        public static void AddSwaggerPage(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSwaggerGen();

            services.ConfigureSwaggerGen(options =>
            {
                options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Version = ...,
                    Title = ...,
                    Description = ...
                });
                services.AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport();
                
                ...and a bunch of auth stuff...
            }
        }
```

Note that I've tried putting the AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport *outside* of the ConfigureSwaggerGen call, but doing so caused any fetch of swagger.json to hit HTTP 500. Here's the interesting part of the exception:

```
{
    "Error": {
        "Message": "Failed to generate Operation for action - Project.Host.Controllers.ThingController.GetThingSettings (Project.Host). See inner exception",
        "Data": {},
        "InnerException": {
            "Message": "Failed to generate schema for type - GetThingSettings. See inner exception",
            "Data": {},
            "InnerException": {
                "ClassName": "System.NullReferenceException",
                "Message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
                "Data": null,
                "InnerException": null,
                "HelpURL": null,
                "StackTraceString": "   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GenerateSchemaForMember(Type modelType, SchemaRepository schemaRepository, MemberInfo memberInfo, DataProperty dataProperty)\r\n   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.CreateObjectSchema(DataContract dataContract, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)\r\n   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GenerateReferencedSchema(DataContract dataContract, SchemaRepository schemaRepository, Func`1 definitionFactory)\r\n   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GenerateConcreteSchema(DataContract dataContract, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)\r\n   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GenerateSchemaForType(Type modelType, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)\r\n   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GenerateSchema(Type type, SchemaRepository schemaRepository, PropertyInfo propertyInfo, ParameterInfo parameterInfo, ApiParameterRouteInfo routeInfo)",
```

GetThingSettings is boring-but-nested, with several basic types in it. The weirdest one is a Dictionary<ThingEnum, BasicValuesClass>, where ThingEnum is an enum.

```
public enum ThingEnum
{
    Thing1,
    Thing2,
    Thing3
}

public class GetThingSettings 
{
    public Dictionary<string, List<int>> Lists { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<ThingEnum, ThingEnabled> ThingEnabled { get; set; }
}

public class ThingEnabled {
    public bool? All { get; set; }
    public List<int> Included { get; set; }
    public List<int> Excluded { get; set; }
}
```

##### Code that generates the wrong property name in swagger.json, from an in-house Nuget package

```
namespace Thingy
{
    public class Document
    {
        // This right here gets ignored. The generated swagger.json has this as "eTag", not "_etag".
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "_etag", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string ETag { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**So: what error am I making in making Swagger recognize the Newtonsoft attributes?**

Answer (score 1):

I would try use `services.AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport()` outside `services.ConfigureSwaggerGen()`, like in the [example](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/8f363f7359cb1cb8fa5de5195ec6d97aefaa16b3/test/WebSites/NetCore21/Startup.cs#L38) and [README](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/tree/8f363f7359cb1cb8fa5de5195ec6d97aefaa16b3#systemtextjson-stj-vs-newtonsoft).

Example from README:

```
services.AddMvc();

services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
});
services.AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport(); // explicit opt-in - needs to be placed after AddSwaggerGen()
```

Comment: When I tried that, attempts to fetch the swagger.json would meet with HTTP 500 due to NullReferenceException while trying to generate one of the types. I looked at the type, and it was pretty boring: several nested dictionaries, classes, etc that all ended in primitives. I'll update the question with the exception I'm getting.